# Remove xmlns from the root tag while preserve other tags such as xmlns:xsd and xmlns:xsi

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-namespaces

I am not very familiar with XSLT. I am trying to remove the xmlns namespace from the root tag while preserve other tags like xmlns:xsd and xmlns:xsi using xslt. I got some help from internet to remove the xmlns namespace but that code is also removing xmlns:xsd. Please help. Thanks in advance.

This is my xsl code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0"
 xmlns:old="http://www.example.com"    exclude-result-prefixes="old">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="old:*">
   <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is  my input xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data xmlns="http://www.example.com" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/schemaLocation">

<name>abc</name>
<name>efg</name>

</Data>
```

On running my XSL on the input XML I get the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/schemaLocation">

<name>abc</name>
<name>efg</name>

</Data>
```

Desired Output XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/schemaLocation">

<name>abc</name>
<name>efg</name>

</Data>
```

Comment: Note: you're **not** "*trying to remove the xmlns namespace from the root tag*". You want to move **all** elements out of their namespace  (defined as the *default namespace* in the root element opening tag) into no-namespace - essentially renaming all elements in the given XML document.

Answer (score 0):

The missing namespace declaration is not used anywhere in the XML document, so your processor is quite right in discarding it.

You may try and force it to be copied:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="@* | namespace::*[name()]"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but not all processors will produce the hoped-for result (Xalan, for example, won't).

Comment: There's a very good reason for wanting to retain the `xmlns:xsd` declaration: it might well be used in an attribute such as `xsi:type="xsd:dateTime"`. In general an XSLT processor can't detect when namespace prefixes are used inside attribute content, which is why they aren't discarded by default.

Comment: @MichaelKay I believe the content of an attribute is a string - and a string cannot have a "namespace prefix" as such.

Comment: In a PSVI (or in XDM) the content of an attribute can be a QName rather than a string. (xsi:type is implicitly declared as a QName.) And even the document  hasn't been validated yet, it might be validated in the future, and removing the namespace would cause the validation to fail.